# Creating OAuth connection for Google Calendar API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, google-api

I'm using this gem https://github.com/unixcharles/google_calendar_api_v2 
which is built on https://github.com/oauth/oauth-ruby

In the client class it creates a connection as follows:

```
  def initialize(consumer_key, consumer_secret, token, token_secret)
    consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key, consumer_secret, {
      :site               => "https://www.google.com",
      :scheme             => :header
    })
    @connection = OAuth::AccessToken.new(consumer,token, token_secret)

    @calendars = Calendar.new(@connection)
  end
```

For the consumer_key do I put what the Google API console lists as 'Client ID'?
For the consumer_secret do I put what the Google API console lists as 'Client secret'? 
I know the token is what I get back after the OAuth authentication. 
And I assume I set token_secret to "" ?

This is what I'm doing and I keep getting:

```
"GoogleCalendarApiV2::AuthenticationError (GoogleCalendarApiV2::AuthenticationError):"
```

when I call:

```
  client = GoogleCalendarApiV2::Client.new {'Client ID'}, {'Client secret'}, params[:access_token], ""
  calendar = client.calendars.all
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The client id is your domain.

Should look like this:

```
client = GoogleCalendarApiV2::Client.new 'teambox.com', 'some_secret_key_for_your_domain', 'oauth_token_for_the_user', 'oauth_secret_for_the_user'
```

Remember that this Gem is for OAuth1 and the APIv2, the newer APIv3 doesn't work like this. It use OAuth2 which is different.

Answer (score 0):

Calendar API v3 is supported by the new Google APIs Client Library for Ruby:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/